# CAS + service worker endless redirect loop

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, service-worker, cas

I have a problem with my service worker. I use CAS for logging in to my application. When I close the web page and try to open it again, I receive the following error:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly 
An error occurred during a connection to start.oacloud.org. 
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6OWi.png) is a screenshot showcasing the redirect loop.

Here is my service worker:

```
cacheName = 'portal-cache';
const staticAssets = [
  'portal_.php',
  'css/portal.css',
  'css/portalI.css',
  'css/portalJ.css',
  'css/portalE.css',
  'js/jquery-ui.css',
  'js/jquery.js',
  'js/jquery-ui.js',
  'js/lodash.js',
  'portal.js',
  'js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js',
  'js/jquery-ui.structure.css',
  'js/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
  'js/jquery-ui.theme.css',
  'js/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event)
{
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(staticAssets);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e)
{
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response)
    {
      if (response)
      {
        return response;
      }
      else
      {
        return fetch(event.request).then(function(res)
        {
            return caches.open('portal-dynamic')
              .then(function(cache)
              {
                cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                return res;
              })
        }).catch(function(err)
        {
          return caches.open('error messages').then(function(cache)
          {
            return cache.match('portal_.php');
          });
        });
      }
    })
  );
});
```

What exactly am I doing wrong that allows this loop to happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by fetching first from the internet, then from cache:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    var requestURL = new URL(event.request.url);
    if(requestURL.host =='your CAS server' || (requestURL.host =='page to redirect to' && requestURL.pathname == 'your server')){
    console.log('IN: '+requestURL);
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request)
        .catch(function() {
            return new Response('{status: \'no internet connection\'}',
                {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }, status : 404}
            );
        }));
    return;
}

console.log('The service worker is serving the asset.');
event.respondWith(
    //check first if the request is for a static asset and serve it directly from cache
    caches.open(cacheStatic).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response ||
            //if asset is not in static cache try to take it from the network
            fetch(event.request).then(function(responseD) {
                //save it in dynamic cache for when there is no network
                return caches.open(cacheDynamic).then(function(cacheD) {
                    cacheD.put(event.request, responseD.clone());
                    return responseD;
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('catch: '+requestURL);
                //if unable to take it from the network, take it from dynamic cache
                return caches.open(cacheDynamic).then(function(cacheD) {
                    return cacheD.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                        return response || new Response('{status: \'no internet connection\'}',
                                {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }, status : 404}
                            );
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    })
)
});
```